# How to add / into the preg_replace pattern

Tags: php, preg-replace

I made this simple function to filter the data. I add the symbols that I allow to be included but I dont know how to add **/** symbol as well

```
public function filter($text)
  {
     return preg_replace('/[^^a-zA-Z0-9#@:_(),.!@" ]/','',$text);
  }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can either escape it with a backslash:

```
preg_replace('/\//' ...);
```

Or use other characters as delimiters:

```
preg_replace('|/|' ...);
```

Comment: personally i like using # as delimiter, you almost never need it.

Answer (score 5):

Simply escape the character with a backslash.

```
public function filter($text)
  {
     return preg_replace('/[^^a-zA-Z0-9#@:_(),.!@"\/ ]/','',$text);
  }
```